# store part of an executable string as a variable using t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

Instead of

```
WHERE foo = 'one' and bar = 'two'
```

I would like to store parts of it in a variable to allow changing WHERE clause easily

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(50)
SET @var = "foo = 'one' and bar = 'two'"
...
...
WHERE @var
```

This notation doesn't work but I think it indicates what I am trying to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Here's an idea: don't do that. It's plain and simply wrong.

Comment: The search term is "sql server dynamic where".

Comment: Hi Crono, what makes it wrong? I am working in a scenario where there wont be a GUI to aid selection, I was using this a method to easily change the WGERE clause using only T-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build dynamic where clauses, you're better off using dynamic sql.

Take a look at the following article: [Dynamic SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Also this article: [Another Article...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

and here's a simple dynamic SQL code example:

Here's a SP that uses dynamic SQL to determine what to order by:

```
create procedure GetCustomers
    @OrderByField nVarchar(50),
    @OrderByDirection nVarchar(4)
as
begin

declare @strSQl nvarchar(200)

set @strSQL = 'Select firstname, lastname from customer order by ' + @OrderByField + ' ' + @OrderByDirection 

exec sp_execute @strSQL

end
```

then you can run it:

```
exec GetCustomers 'lastname','desc'
```

this will return all customers ordered by lastname desc

Comment: -1 because you did not provide adequate supporting information, such as an example. If you fix it, I'll remove my vote.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray edited with example.

Comment: That looks good to me and helps improve the quality of the post. I'll remove my downvote and supply it with an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the dynamic sql route, try this:

```
declare @foo varchar(10)
        ,@bar varchar(10)
        ,@sql varchar(max)

select @foo = 'one'
        ,@bar = 'two'


SET @sql = '

    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE foo = ''' + @foo + ''' 
    AND bar = ''' + @bar + '''
'

EXEC (@SQL)
```